# How to assign shortcut keys that can be used from external keyboard in iOS app to trigger particular button (UIControl) in voiceover mode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to set few shortcut to commonly used buttons/controls in my app only when voiceover mode is turned on. This short cuts should be used from external keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `BOOL UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning();` also you should subscribe to voice over change notification `UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged`.

And probably you should make a subclass of UIApplication to handle application scope shortcuts keys. But it also depends what you need, maybe it will be enough for you to handle events on view controller level. Here you should chose solution, which suit you better.

Comment: I tried it with overriding UIApplication and - (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event method in it, but event is coming as 'UIInternalEvent' from external keyboard, and it's a private API.

Comment: Take a look to ``UIResponder`` documentation, from iOS 7 it has a property ``@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *keyCommands``, it might be something what you are looking for.